# How to make an array of markers on a Google map taking addresses from html?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to make an array of markers on a Google map by taking the longitudes and latitudes from an array in html.erb file but I don't know how to send longitudes and latitudes and make the markers.

```
var map;
var place1;
var defaultZoom = 16;
var mylat = '30.04441';
var mylng = '31.23571';
var centrePoint = new google.maps.LatLng(mylat, mylng);
var markerX;

//rendering the map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadMap);

// create map and add controls 
function loadMap() {
    //map options
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.0444196, 31.23571160000006),//center in cairo
        zoom: defaultZoom,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scaleControl      : false,
        scrollwheel       : false,
        draggable         : true,
        mapTypeControl    : false,
        panControl        : false,
        zoomControl       : true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
        style   : google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,//zoom out and in at the map
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
        }
    };
    //new map from google maps
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'),mapOptions);
}


and this is the html.erb
favorite_place is an object with attributes contains longitude and latitude in database

 <h1>My Favorite Places</h1>
    <% @favorite_places.each do |favorite_place| %>
<p><%=link_to truncate(favorite_place.name,length:19,omission:'',separator:','), controller: "favorite_places", action:"show",id:favorite_place.id  %> </p>
<div id="google-map" class="map_new" ></div>
<%end%>
```

Comment: why dont you write the ruby code in the javascript directly?

Comment: also, to answer your question we would need to know what the ruby code puts out

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to display Marker on Map

```
Marker marker=map.add(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Lat1,Lng1)).title("Place_name"));
```

Here map is a GoogleMap object and Lat1 and Lng1 should be the Latitude and Longitude respectively of the place you want to display.

Comment: I know how to put a single marker with lng and lat from variables in javascript but I want to have an array in html.erb from the favorite_places and send it to the javascript and make an array of markers @RahulSolanki

Comment: @Korem  I know how to put a single marker with lng and lat from variables in javascript but I want to have an array in html.erb from the favorite_places and send it to the javascript and make an array of markers